# Android, sending values to the ASP net webservice

Tags: android, asp.net, xml, android-asynctask

I am struggling with sending values to web service methods. Currently I am trying to create login page activity, where I am getting login name and password. On click of login button I am sending values gotten from edittext's...However I have no idea in which format data is sent?is it just string, XML or JSON data.

I am using source provided at link http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/ as a reference

```
   public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String name, String webMethName) {
    String resTxt = null;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Name
    sayHelloPI.setName("Name");
    // Set Value
    sayHelloPI.setValue(name);
    // Set dataType
    sayHelloPI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(sayHelloPI);
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //Set envelope as dotNet
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to resTxt variable static variable
        resTxt = response.toString();
```

In the code provided above a property added to the request and sent. The question is in which format that property is sent.

Comment: Can you provide any source code? Mysterious question.

Comment: just added sample code that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you are using some sort of Soap client library. So the message which is sent to server has to be in [XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Message_format). I guess the object `sayHelloPI` is deserialized to XML during HTTP request.